# Write output in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am using get-childitem to get Filename, loction & size.

`$agh=get-childitem E:\Documents\ -recurse | % {Write-output $_.FullName $_.length}`

I am getting output like below.

E:\Documents\Application Remediation - What to look for.pptx
55956
E:\Documents\Estimation of time required for changes.xlsx
10509

I am getting filename in one line and size in new line.

I am expecting output like below

`File name                                       Location         Size

Application Remediation - What to look for.pptx E:\Documents\    55956
Estimation of time required for changes.xlsx    E:\Documents\    10509`

Need help in how to format write-output in foreach loop to redirect in a variable.

I am going to use this variable in Mail body to share details of directory as email contents.

Thanks.

Comment: `get-childitem c:\temp\ -recurse | select FullName, length | ft` to get table format.

Comment: `get-childitem c:\temp\ -recurse | select Name, Directory, length | ft` will get the three items as you specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipe the output to a SELECT statement to get the name, path, and size, and then to Format-Table:

```
$agh = get-childitem E:\Documents\ -recurse | select Name, Directory, length | format-table
```

Comment: If that is not what you're needing, you'll need to edit the question to provide more specific information.  If the email is being rendered as HTML, you'll probably need to enclose the output in a <pre> tag so that it will be monotype and all of the spaces will be rendered.

Comment: `DirectoryInfo` object does not have `Directory` property. And you do not need to `select`, you can ask `Format-Table` to display specific properties directly: `ft @{l='File name';e='Name'},@{l='Location';e={[IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($_.FullName)}},@{l='Size';e='Length'}`.

Comment: Are you sure it works for `DirectoryInfo` (not `FileInfo`) object?

Comment: You're right--I didn't read it carefully enough--it doesn't have it for directories.  Likely he doesn't want the directory objects listed in the output anyway, since any files in the directory will be listed.

Comment: Hi TonyHinkle and @PetSerAl, Both of your commands helped me to get the desire output. Thanks for sharing the same. Now another challenge for me is that File names and Path are too long to fit in a table column. So when I am getting email with information of long file names, ending with three dots(...) which show that text is skipped. I tried using -autosize but No help. I guess I have to use format-list instead of format-table. If you have any suggestion with Format table then please share the same.

Comment: Try `format-table -autosize -wrap`   This causes text that overflows a column to wrap below.  Another option would be remove format-table and use convertto-html instead, which will give you an HTML table.